# Angular submit hander not logging data to the console

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created the following angular component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'weather-search',
    template: `
        <section>
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" let f="ngForm" class="search__form">
                <label for="search_city">Enter City</label>
                <input ngControl="location" type="text" id="search_city"  placeholder="Enter City" required/>
                <button type="submit">Add City</button>
            </form>
            <div class="locationsearch__info">
                <span class="info">City Found</span>:<span>Kansas</span>
            </div>
        </section>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./weather-search.component.css']
}) 


export class WeatherSearchComponent {
    onSubmit(form: FormGroup) {
        console.log(form);
    }
}
```

I am using this component in my app.component.ts like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <weather-search></weather-search>
  <weather-list></weather-list>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
```

Now the thing is when i click on submit i expect that the submit will be stopped and the form data will be `console.log`'ed, thats not whats happening right now , just to give a brief preview of my code, notice how i have a local variable `let f="ngForm"` and on submit i am passing this variable to the submit handler like so `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)"`.

As of now though on submit i see nothing in the console. Why is my submit handler not working ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use # symbol to define a local variable like this in your case:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" class="search__form">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

**template :**

```
<form name="f" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" class="search__form"></form>
```

**typescript :**

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export class HomeComponent {
    onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
        console.log('f', f);
    }
}
```